# Firemonkey styled TMemo does not get focus

Tags: delphi, tmemo, firemonkey-style

I dropped a `TMemo` and a regular `TStyleBook` on a Form. I edited the custom style for the `TMemo` by adding a `TRectangle` to `background` so `TMemo` now has a different background color, and changed the `TMemo.StyleLookup` property to the actual `StyleName`, but at runtime the `TMemo` can not get focus.

```
unit Form1;

interface

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm1)
    Memo1: TMemo;
    StyleBook1: TStyleBook;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}

end.
```

[image: StyleBook_StyledMemo]

What I am missing?

Comment: Make sure HitTest is set to False on the Rectangle

Comment: @user2383818 you mean Dave, not me.

Comment: Yes Dave. My mistake.

Comment: @DaveNottage. I did. It is set to False. Same for background, content, etc. I tried also setting a TRectangle as the MemoStyle. This way, the TMemo is focused but the cursor caret is placed over the TRectangle stroke border even if I set the Padding property to any value. This is very frustrating and time consuming, time that I should spent developing my application

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that for setting properties to be applied to the background of the `tMemo`, the original `background` item must be replaced by a `tRectangle` and it's `StyleName` assigned with `background`. All items inside the original `background`, must be transferred to the new `tRectangle` `background` and the original must be deleted. The `Align` property of the `tRectangle` `background` must be set to  `Contents` and The `Align` property of the `contents` item must be set to `Client`. After that, any property of the new `tRectangle` `background` can be set to the desired value and they will be properly displayed at design and run time. Finally yes, the `tMemo` can be focused!

```
StyleContainer
...
Memo1Style1
   ...
   background
   ...
...
```

`background` above, must be a `tRectangle`